# Power supply for a laptop

Tags: windows-7

it's correct to keep the power supply cord plugged all the time to the laptop even if the laptop has been turned off

Comment: Correct in what sense?  To keep the battery charged?  To reduce power consumption?

Answer (score 2):

There is no one answer fits all.

The best thing you can buy is an electricity meter device and test for yourself. Some are intelligent enough and do not draw electricity when not in use - however there are some the pull a low charge even when not in use.

[image]

Personally, there is nothing to gain so I would turn it off if it is not being used.

Answer (score 1):

Older laptop power bricks used to consume current at idle (sometimes a LOT) but nowadays it's rare to find one that runs more than a watt or two with power off.  If it feels warm to the touch it's probably worth unplugging.  Cold to the touch and I probably wouldn't bother.

The only other benefit I can think of to unplugging is that a power surge (like lightning nearby) will be less likely to damage your equipment.